# Groovy: Handling nested JSON array objects efficiently

Tags: json, groovy

Here is a sample data of JSON that contains nested array of JSON objects.

```
def content = """[{
  "student" : {
    "studentId" : "ABC001",
    "studentName" : "TOM"
    },
    "details" : {
        "subjects" : {
            "subjectDetails" : [{
                "name" : "MATHS",
                "rating" : 4
            },
            {
                "name" : "SPANISH",
                "rating" : 5
            }
            ]
        }
    }
  },
  {
    "student" : {
    "studentId" : "DEF222",
    "studentName" : "RICK"
    },
    "details" : {
        "subjects" : {
            "subjectDetails" : null
        }
    }
  },
  {
  "student" : {
    "studentId" : "XYZ444",
    "studentName" : "AMY"
    },
    "details" : {
        "subjects" : {
            "subjectDetails" : [{
                "name" : "MATHS",
                "rating" : 6
            },
            {
                "name" : "SPANISH",
                "rating" : 7
            },
            {
                "name" : "PHYSICS",
                "rating" : 9
            }
            ]
        }
    }
  }]"""
```

Having a JSON content containing multiple nested JSON array objects which has to be separated out as child records.
Tried the below code but would like to know if there are efficient ways of doing this incase there are multiple nested arrays.
My expected output is below.

```
def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)

def header = "type," + result.collect{it.student.keySet()}.unique().flatten().join(",")
println header
def childHeader = {try {
    result.details.subjects.subjectDetails.flatten().collect {it.keySet()}.unique().flatten().join(",")
    } catch(Exception e) {'exception'}
}

result.collect {
    students = it.student
    studentsRecord = "Parent," + students.collect { it.value }.join(",")
    println studentsRecord

    subjects = it.details.subjects.subjectDetails

    subjectsRecord = subjects.collect{"Subject-Children," + it.values().join(",")}.join("\n") ?:''
    if (subjectsRecord)
        println subjectsRecord
}
```

Output:

```
type,studentId,studentName
Parent,ABC001,TOM
Subject-Children,MATHS,4
Subject-Children,SPANISH,5
Parent,DEF222,RICK
Parent,XYZ444,AMY
Subject-Children,MATHS,6
Subject-Children,SPANISH,7
Subject-Children,PHYSICS,9
```

Comment: How to estimate efficiency? Performance? Code size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut that down to:

```
def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)

println "type,${result.student.head().keySet().join(',')}"
result.each { student ->
    println "Parent,${student.student.values().join(',')}"
    student.details.subjects.subjectDetails.each {
        println "Subject-Children,$it.name,$it.rating"
    }
}
```

Not sure how you want to measure efficiency though

Do you have an example with "multiple nested arrays"?

Comment: Thank you `tim`. Will post that as a different question.